# How to prove $1993|82^{83}+1$

Tags: number-theory

How to prove (without computer )
$$1993|82^{83}+1$$

I have know $1993$ is prime number.and $1992=2^3\times 3\times 83$.so use Fermat's Little Theorem I only prove
$$82^{1992}=1\pmod {1993}$$

But How to prove 
$$82^{83}\equiv -1\pmod {1993}?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $83=1+2+16+64$. Modulo $1993$ we get $82^{2^n}$ by repeated squaring viz. $$82^2=745,\,82^4=971,\,82^8=152,\,82^{16}=-812,\,82^{32}=-339,\,82^{64}=-673.$$Thus $$82^{83}=82\times 745\times 812\times 673=-693\times 394=-1.$$